# How do I get Eclipse to command complete Java Script string related functions

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm doing string manipulation in Java Script. My Eclipse (Luna) is handling command completion for many things, but string functions it is not.

```
var sillyString = "hello";
sillyString.  <- command complete here: ctrl-space triggers a dropdown with nothing in it.
```

I have to use Google to figure out things like this: http://www.sitepoint.com/15-javascript-string-functions/

Command complete works for other Java Script items in my code base.

Answer (score 0):

1. To configure JavaScript Content Assist options:
   Go to the JavaScript Content Assist preferences page, accessed from Window | Preferences | Web |  JavaScript | Editor | Content Assist.
2. Configure the following options, according to your preferences:
   Insertion
   Completion Inserts/Completion Overwrites - Select whether choosing an item from the Content Assist list  will cause new code to be entered or existing code to be overwritten.
   Insert single proposals automatically -If enabled, the content assist suggestion will be inserted automatically when only one content assist option exists
   Insert common prefixes automatically -  If enabled, Content Assist will automatically insert the common prefix of all possible completions similar to Unix shell expansion. This can be used repeatedly, even while the Content Assist window is being displayed.
3. Click Apply to apply your settings.

taken from this link [eclipse Javascript intelisense](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm)

Comment: Content assist is enabled. It just doesn't work that well. For example: var name = "bob"; bob.  <- ctrlSpace, won't reveal what's available for this string type.